# Excel and R do not see two values as being equal

Tags: r, excel

I loaded data into two Excel sheets from online tables. Both tables include distinct information about the same group of baseball players, who are named in column B (or column 2 when converted to R) of each table. Neither Excel (VLOOKUP/MATCH) nor R will match up the players' names between the two tables, despite those names looking exactly the same in every way.

Yes, I have checked for extra spaces, capitalization, etc. I have attempted reformatting the cells in Excel that include the players' names. Please see input and output below from R (data was loaded as csv file):

```
> as.character(freeagentvalue$Name)[3064]
[1] "Travis Hafner"
> as.character(freeagentdata$Name)[294]
[1] "Travis Hafner"
> as.character(freeagentdata$Name)[294] == as.character(freeagentvalue$Name)[3064]
[1] FALSE
```

I would appreciate any information on why Excel and R are finding differences like the one above. Otherwise I have to retype a lot of names. Thank you in advance.

Comment: My R says those are equal... I guess we will need a `dput(head(freeagentdata$Name))`

Comment: I don't know about `R`, but with regard to `Excel`, it is likely that there is some difference.  Without access to the original tables, I couldn't tell you what.  I would suggest you look at the character code for each character in two names that look the same but won't match.  It may be that in one table, the `space` is a normal space `CODE=32`, whereas in the other, the `space` is really a `NBSP` CODE=160

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two `Travis Hafner` strings in your example above differ in that in that the first example has a NBSP between the two names; the second has a normal `space`.

I suggest preprocessing the tables by Replacing all NBSP's with `space`  You can do that either on the worksheet, using the SUBSTITUTE function; or in VBA, using Replace.

Comment: You can see the byte differences with `charToRaw(as.character(freeagentvalue$Name)[3064])` and `charToRaw(as.character(freeagentdata$Name)[294])`. They differ at the 7th byte.